# ASP.NET MVC4 - Multiple add in multiple textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, post

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC4. I want to offer the possibility to add multiples records (from 1 to 3 maximum) by displaying a view with multiple textboxes which finally represents the same things.

For instance, in my View, I would like to have something like this :

> Start hour (1) : |TextBoxForHours| h |TextBoxForMinutes|
>
> Start hour (2) : |TextBoxForHours| h |TextBoxForMinutes|
>
> Start hour (3) : |TextBoxForHours| h |TextBoxForMinutes|

In my controller, I'll check how many textboxes have been filled and save it in my db.

Here's the ViewModel I've created to do that :

```
public class DeniedIntervalsViewModel
{
    public int StartHour { get; set; }

    public int StartMinute { get; set; }


}
```

Any idea to do that?

Comment: You could create typed partial view that would accept `DeniedIntervalsViewModel`  that has 2 inputs (`StartHour`, `StartMinute`), then add it 3 times to form. In your controller you would accept `List<DeniedIntervalsViewModel>`, and then you would process the values.

Answer (score 0):

you can use input naming convention for Array, List, Collection or dictionary like this

### [Updates]

Oneway inputs:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    <div>
        <label>Start hour :</label>
        <input type="text" name="intervals[@i].StartHour " value="" />
        <input type="text" name="intervals[@i].StartMinute " value="" />
    </div>
}
```

To bind ViewModel back to View:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    <div>
        <label>Start hour :</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Intervals[i].FirstName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Intervals[i].LastName)
    </div>
}
```

and your parent ViewModel contains array

```
public class TheViewModel{

    public DeniedIntervalsViewModel[] Intervals{ get; set; }
}

public class TheController{

    public ActionResult Blah(DeniedIntervalsViewModel[] intervals) {
      // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: use this and every time you will need to add additional field you will be copy pasting it n times in form.

Comment: Sure You can loop through collection to render inputs. see update